# Multiplying two numbers

Tags: arithmetic

I've come across this technique to multiply two numbers of multiple digits and its not long multiplication. I'd appreciate it if someone could throw some light on why it works or the logic behind it.

```
1 2 3
x 4 5 6
-------
1 x 456 =  4  5 6
2 x 456 =     8 10 12
3 x 456 =       12 15 18
----------------------------
 sum    =  4 13 28 27 18
----------------------------
fix carry =  5  6  0  8  8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* long multiplication. You've just saved up all the carries to do all at once at the end. You are doing exactly the same multiplications, carries, and additions you would do in long multiplication.

But it does shed some light on why long multiplication works, doesn't it?

Comment: interesting, I dint know you could delay carry like that

Comment: I believe this is either _the_ technique or closely related to the traditional technique the Chinese developed for multiplication.  (Works just fine...)

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly long multiplication with carries delayed.